# g++ insists <cmath> doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, header, g++, mingw

So, I recently re-installed windows, and am currently trying to set up again, so I'm trying to re-compile some code that worked pre-reinstall. What I'm currently having trouble with is the fact that upon compilation, I get errors implying that I don't have standard libraries:

```
g++ -c -Wall -g -v src/main.cpp -o src/main.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-Wall' '-g' '-v' '-o' 'src/main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ src/main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase-strip src/main.o -g -Wall -version -o C:\Users\Maphrox\AppData\Local\Temp\ccS1atrn.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "i:/p/giaw/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: e3b01b00b6cf2cc1dc95350e55dafc7d
In file included from c:\mingw\include\glm\glm.hpp:78:0,
                 from src/main.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\include\glm\core/_fixes.hpp:29:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory
 #include <cmath>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'm pretty much sure that the cause of the problem is reinstalling windows.

Comment: Windows really doesn't like forward slashes, and mixed slashes are even worse. I'd take a careful look at your path and other environment variables.

Comment: Sounds like a broken installation, have you verified where the file lives actually?

Comment: @Vicky No – Forward slashes are completely fine in Windows and have been for a looong time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry, but I disagree. I'm running Windows 7 here and for example if I open a command prompt and type `cd blah/` then hit tab for auto complete options, it doesn't work properly (the auto complete options show me the directories at the current level, not under `blah\`). That's just one single example where it doesn't do what you would expect.

Comment: @Vicky In programming, that is, things like `iostream` paths or `#include` paths, forward slashes have been working on Windows for quite some time.

Comment: @Vicky I don’t know about auto completion but **as a path specifier**, every Windows file system function will accept forward slashes. So if you said `cd blah/foo` and hit <Return> then the prompt will comply.

Comment: Did you verify that the libraries are there?

Comment: Well, libm.a and math.h are both present, and the path variable doesn't have anything that immediately strikes me as wrong (All I've added is ";C:\MinGW\bin" (Without the "s, of course.)